# Does A New Installation Contain Personal Information?

Tags: apple-id, install, macos

I am going to sell my MacBook Air when the new MacBook comes out and so I want to make sure there is no personal Information available to the next user.

I am going to wipe my SSD and reinstall the OS however since I have to download the installer from the App Store will information like my Apple ID be copied onto the computer during the installation?

Comment: maybe...to be sure download a installer on bootable USB and do it from there, this way the old mac newer saw your Apple ID after disk wipe.

Comment: That is how I was going to do it. Do you think that Apple will give me any tips on how to make sure there is no data on my old Air when I get the new MacBook?

Comment: they do here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065  lets make this a answer so you can reward me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the apple instructions here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065

Download OS X on to bootable USB and reinstall it from there.

This way you do not have to use your Apple ID.

Comment: It says on the link you gave me to do all of it from disk utility instead of a bootable USB. So what shall I do? For now I will do what Apple says unless you say different.

Comment: That is your choice, I would use USB.

Comment: What is the difference between USB and Disk Utility method from Apple?

Comment: With Disk utility you have to go online to get (download) the install using your old mac. With USB you do not, thus no record of any kind.

Comment: Ah, Ok. Then why would Apple suggest that then?

Answer (score 1):

No, no personal information is stored unless you enter any. If you're performing a clean installation of OS X then simply set it up with a temporary administrator account, no need to sign into iCloud or register etc.